# Running mysqlclient on python with django

Tags: python, mysql, django

https://www.pythoncentral.io/writing-your-first-python-django-application/

I am following this tutorial on Django for Python. I have reached and installed the mysql-python (mysqlclient in python 3 which I am using) step. However I do not understand what he means by "..execute the following statements in a mysql shell.."

> mysql> CREATE USER 'pythoncentral'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY '12345';
>
> mysql> CREATE DATABASE myblog;
>
> mysql> GRANT ALL ON myblog.* TO 'pythoncentral'@'localhost';

My problem is I do not know what program I need to enter these commands into.

I have tried imputing the commands in:

- cmd.exe at the location of my django folder (myblog)
- on the mysql shell (https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/shell/)

In the command window "python -m pip list" shows me mysqlclient is installed, however, python -m mysql (or mysqlclient, mysqldb etc) returns "No module named mysql"

In the mysql shell, I have not been able to run the above commands either but I am less familiar with it compared to the command window.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Find out where mysql is installed then move to that folder and run these commands to open the shell
In my case it is

```
C:\>cd \MYSQL\Bin
C:\MYSQL\Bin>mysql -u root -p admin
```

'root' is mysql username and 'admin' is my password replace it with you own and you would be able to login and execute those commands.